# models/tutorials/rnn/ptb fails on R1.4 line 271 no attribute RNNParamsSaveable

Tags: python, tensorflow

the API contrib.cudnn_rnn.RNNParamsSaveable has been deprecated in r1.4, but is used in the tensorflow tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent. It is not entirely clear how to modify lines 271->276 in ptb_word_lm.py to use the new API which presumably should be contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTMSaveable for a default run. Can somebody enlighten me on what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I change the code as follows, then it works:

```
if self._cell and rnn_params:
    params_saveable = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTMSaveable(
        rnn_params,
        self._cell.num_layers,
        self._cell.num_units,
        self._cell.input_size,
        self._cell.input_mode,
        self._cell.direction,
        scope="Model/RNN")
```

remove this line"tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS, params_saveable)"